# Anaconda: Can't install astropy's latest version

Tags: anaconda, conda, astropy, windows-11

Cutting to the chase. Astropy 5.1 has a [compatibility problem](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/14210) with NumPy versions 1.24+. When using the Anaconda Prompt in Windows 11

```
conda install astropy
```

or

```
conda update astropy
```

it installs astropy 5.1 and not the latest version ([5.3](https://www.astropy.org/)). When I force version 5.2, it either says that the version is not available or it enters a permanent loop.

The link I provided above says that AstroPy 5.2 fixed the issue I have with with NumPy. How can I force conda to install the latest version?

ETA: I downgraded numpy as a workaround, and it works. However, it's not ideal, is it?

Comment: If you encounter an error saying that the version is not available or if it enters a permanent loop, it could indicate that the latest version of Astropy (5.3) is not yet available in the default conda channels or there might be some other conflicting dependencies.

Comment: @Ali I thought so initially, but Anaconda says astropy is available as version 5.3 https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/astropy

Comment: Indeed the most recent astropy available in the conda main channel is version 5.1. For a more recent version (5.3 as of this writing) you can use `-c conda-forge astropy=5.3` to install.

Comment: I swear I did exactly that a couple of days ago, but now it worked. Thank you!

Comment: ETA: It broke my code again. I guess I'll be using NumPy 1.23 and Astropy 5.1 for now.

Comment: "*Anaconda Prompt*" - just FYI, I do not recommend using Conda Forge with Anaconda **base**. They are effectively incompatible. The Conda Forge channel is tested with `conda-forge` prioritized and Anaconda **base** assumes `anaconda` (or `defaults`) is the priority. Most people encountering "infinite solve times" are using running into this. If you want an environment with the latest packages then create a new one with Conda Forge as the priority.

Comment: "*it's not ideal, is it?*" depends - what's ideal is something that reliably gets your task done. Unless there is some feature that you absolutely require in NumPy >1.23 and AstroPy > 5.1, then you're fine.